# animate.css - Detect the animation end

Tags: jquery, animate.css

I am using `animate.css` and try to detect the animation end function

```
$('bitinput').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animation end', alert('hello'));
```

but the alert message pop up even before the animation start. What seems to be the problem?

**Updated:**

Here is my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XVqfQzf69nGE3E9yDCXq?p=preview)

Comment: Create a demo of the issue for us to check it.

Comment: Please check the update. I added plunk.